# Drag down excel formulas depending on bloomberg

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file which I import data from bloomberg via the function BDH. I can easily update bloomberg formulas, but the other columns with excel formulas are not updated, so currently I need to drag down the excel formulas everyday. I have already tried to use the code but it does not work. Can someone help me on that? Thank you very much

```
Sub update_formulas()

Activeworkbook.RefreshAll

End sub
```

Comment: Can you show/explain what you've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: Surely you can see nobody would know what you are talking about.

Comment: Is calculation set to automatic? If yes, they should update as soon as the BDH updates the values. if not, then are they UDF? If yes, have you put the option `Application.Volatile` to tell the UDFs to update on value changes? Finally, what does "this macro doesn't work" mean? Compile error? Run-time error? Just nothing?

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+ALT+F9 is the keyboard shortcut for a full recalculation.

`Application.CalculateFullRebuild` is another way to force a refresh of an entire workbook's formulas if want to use VBA.

Note that `RefreshAll` is only for refreshing `Data` related items.  It is the same as going to `Data->Refresh->Refresh All`.  It will update Pivot Tables and external connections.  It will generally not update formulas unless they are referencing the data / Pivot Table that was updated.